# Jquery Dialog submit button not firing sometimes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have submit button in jquery dialog window. Sumbit button is not firing sometimes.And this same piece of code is working fine in another webforms in same project.This making totally mad.What would be reason? can anyone help me?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://localhost:6708/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:6708/Scripts/IndexLogin.js"></script>
```

```
                <asp:LinkButton ID="JobSeekerLogin" Text="JOB SEEKER LOGIN" runat="server" OnClick="JobSeekerLogin_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                <div id="login-content">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TexEmail" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id" runat="server" required="required" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TexPassword" placeholder="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheJobSeekerRemember" runat="server" Text="Remember Password" Checked="true"></asp:CheckBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnJobSeekerLogin" runat="server" Text="Job Seeker Login" OnClick="btnJobSeekerLogin_Click" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="forgotPassword" Text="FORGOT PASSWORD?" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="JobSeekerRegistrationPopup" Text="Are You New User?Register Here" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

I tried following

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("[id*=JobSeekerLogin]").live("click", function () {
        $("#login-content").dialog({
            open: function(type,data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            },
            title: "JOB SEEKER LOGIN",
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
        });
        return false;
    });
});


$(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));


$(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form"));
```

**Note**: Without using **UseSubmitBehavior="false"**

Comment: First, As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Second thing Where's the form tag in the code?

Comment: @sanki  I have form tag. I cropped the exact dialog window code. And I am using jquery 1.7 in another webforms with same code. Its working fine there. I could n't find solution. I tried .clik() instead of .live(). But same result. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Try the following alterations:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
$("[id*=JobSeekerLogin]").on("click", function () {
    $("#login-content").dialog({
        open: function(type,data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        },
        title: "JOB SEEKER LOGIN",
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @sanki-  Still not working. I replaced jquery/1.11.1 with  libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js. Now even Jquery dialog window is not working. I tried only .on() without uisng jquery/1.11.1. But no use.  Thanks for reply

Comment: There's  OnClick="JobSeekerLogin_Click" used in your code? Why? Are you trying to execute a function too on click of the button?

Comment: @sanki- Yes.Its Login form(email,password,submit button). By clicking the submit button it connects to sql server to check credentials.